# Why do time evolution semigroups have to be contracting?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, open-quantum-systems

Studying the theory of open quantum systems, some textbooks start by introducing the notion of a semigroup for the time evolution operator $T_t$. The next step then usually is to impose that such a semigroup should be contracting, i.e. $||T_t|| \leq 1$ for every $t\geq0$. This can be found for example in *Open Quantum Systems: An Introduction* by Rivas & Huelga.

Why is it important physically, that the time evolution semigroup is contracting? Why do we not demand that it conserves the norm of a state, i.e. $||T_t|| = 1$?

Update after discussion with Valter Moretti: Is a contracting semigroup always associated to Markovian dynamics? Do all Markovian systems show contracting semigroup time evolutions?

Answer (score 8):

I do not know the general context, but I see that the book deals with *open* systems. The probability is not conserved, in general, for open systems. However it cannot increase (it remains a probability).

The condition $||T_t||\leq 1$ implies $$||T_t\psi|| \leq ||T_t||\: ||\psi_1|| \leq 1 \cdot 1 =1$$ as wanted, if $\psi$ is the normalized initial state vector. On the other hand, if
$$||T_t\psi||\leq 1$$ for every normalized vector $\psi$, the very definition of norm of operator implies $||T_t|| \leq 1$.

In summary, $||T_t||\leq 1$ is **equivalent** to the fact that the probability cannot increase but it may decrease.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was thinking. You point out that probability can only decrease. That is only true for open systems in the Markovian limit. In general, probability can flow back and forth between two coupled systems, so that I would expect $||T_t||>1$ should be possible.

Comment: OK. I am not an expert on open systems, so maybe there is a deeper reason.

Comment: However, as I showed, that requirement is **equivalent** to non increasing probabilities for every given initial state. So the book is assuming this hypothesis.

Comment: True. Maybe I should have phrased my question differently: Do contracting groups only appear with open quantum systems in the Markovian limit? Conversely, do all Markovian systems exhibit contracting semigroup time evolutions?

Comment: Too far from my expertise, sorry